# Can conversation intelligence platform help Sales Teams?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Can the conversation data be used to improve your sales coaching, optimize your sales process, onboard your new sales reps faster, and gain a deeper understanding of your customers. But how do you unlock this data?

Comment: How to attain ultimate wisdom? Such questions can not be answered by mere mortals (unless, of course, more details are provided...)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of providers of conversational AI (I used to work for one) have analytics components as part of their platform which help you analyse conversations, and identifying trends in conversations, eg what your customers ask for, what their most common problems are, etc.